# MySQL Join two tables in resultSet and add new column acording to first table

Tags: php, mysql

`Employee` table

[image: employee]

`Designation` table

[image: designation]

I want to show the designation in my result set from designation table. And I'm searching data using nic.

Help me

Thank you

Comment: what is number field in designation table?

Comment: its for the likn between two tables(its designation number)
4=Helper

Comment: you can show my answer below is perfact

Comment: thanx bt now im using this--$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee E WHERE nic='".$_POST['nic']."' ";
and also im showing data of Employee table using while.so its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select e.serial_no, d.designation, e.name, e.epf_no, e.appointment_date, e.nic, e.dob 
from employee e, designation d 
where e.designation = d.number and e.nic = 'the_number_you_want'
```

Comment: Thanx keune I got it to work after some adjustments...thnz in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

For example if we have to take designation value for `893041699 nic number`

```
select d.designation from designation d
  join employee e on d.number = e.serial_no
  where e.nic=893041699; //example for nic number 893041699
```

Shows output like

```
designation
------------
Helper
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from employee a, designation b where a.serial_no = b.number and a.nic=921560419
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select e.*, d.designation AS desi_name FROM employee AS e LEFT JOIN designation AS d ON e.serial_no=d.number
```

You get in `desi_name`